# Insert numbers in table in sequence but without IDENTITY set

Tags: sql-server, identity, sql-insert, row-number

I have few tables, in one of them I am doing load from excel file and then i am doing insert from select
In target table i have column `id` which doesn't have `IDENTITY` on it and i cannot create it, so I used `ROW_NUMBER()` in my select for  `INSERT`,
however now I am having problem, when next time I'm doing load from file into my temp table from which I am selection data for `INSERT` row number starts from 1 and if iam trying to do insert i am getting error obout problems with Primary key/ So i need to add ID based on id which is already in target table 
for example if in target table last record 1000
first record from new Insert has to have id 1001

```
    INSERT  INTO table1
                    ( Id ,
                      OkeiId ,
                      OkpdId ,
                      OkvedId ,
                   )
                    SELECT 
                    --  (SELECT MAX (id) FROM table1) AS 'last id in table',
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ( SELECT 0 ) ) AS Row , -- Id - int
                            a.[Id] AS OkeId ,  - int
                            c.[Id] AS OkpId , - int
                            D.[Id] AS OkvId ,  - int

                    FROM    [dbo].#table b
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 a ON b.F6 = a.[NationalSymbol]
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 c ON b.F4 = c.Code
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN table4 D ON b.F5 = D.Code
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 f ON b.f1 = f.Code
                    WHERE   f.code IS NULL
```

any Ideas how to continue insert id in sequence? I CANNOT use `IDENTITY` on this table. I hope you can understand my explanetions

Comment: Why can't you use an `IDENTITY` column?, I mean, it's the logical and practical solution for this. You *could* get the `MAX` value for `id` and then use `ROW_NUMBER() + MaxValue`, but what happens if someone else is inserting data on that table?, concurrency seems like it can give you trouble

Comment: @Lamak just because it was like this before me, and its a rule in the company, not to use `IDENTITY` in any of tables. All of IDs has to come from query or from complicated procedure and in this example i was told not to use procedure.

Comment: I know that you are not in charge of that decision, but that must be one of the most ridiculous policies I've ever heard

Comment: @Lamak, its surprising me all the time, i guess architect had some concerns why not to use them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT  INTO table1
                ( Id ,
                  OkeiId ,
                  OkpdId ,
                  OkvedId 
               )
                SELECT 
                --  (SELECT MAX (id) FROM table1) AS 'last id in table',
                a.last_id + ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ( SELECT 0 ) ) AS Row , -- Id - int
                        a.[Id] AS OkeiId , -- OkeiId - int
                        c.[Id] AS OkpdId , -- OkpdId - int
                        D.[Id] AS OkvedId  -- OkvedId - int

                FROM    [dbo].#table b
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 a ON b.F6 = a.[NationalSymbol]
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 c ON b.F4 = c.Code
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN table4 D ON b.F5 = D.Code
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 f ON b.f1 = f.Code
                        CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX (id) AS last_id FROM table1 ) a
                WHERE   f.code IS NULL
```

and some tests:

```
            CREATE TABLE #a
            (
                a INT PRIMARY KEY,
                aa int
            )

            CREATE TABLE #b
            (
                b int
            )

            INSERT INTO #a VALUES(1,1);

            INSERT INTO #b VALUES(1);
            INSERT INTO #b VALUES(2);
            INSERT INTO #b VALUES(3);
            INSERT INTO #b VALUES(4);
            INSERT INTO #b VALUES(5);

            INSERT INTO #a

            SELECT last_id + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY b.b), b.b FROM #b b CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(a) last_id FROM #a) a
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're unable to use [IDENTITY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) for some reason and are on SQL Server 2012+, consider [sequence numbers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878058.aspx). They can be used with multiple columns/tables and are generally more flexible than `IDENTITY`. See below for examples of creation and use.

### Sequence create

```
CREATE SEQUENCE TestSequence
AS INTEGER
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1;
```

### Sequence use

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable
    (
      TestId INTEGER NOT NULL,
      TestColumn CHAR(1) NULL
    );

INSERT INTO TestTable (TestId, TestColumn)
VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR TestSequence, 'A');
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/afde9)